# My ec2 instance terminates after yum update and reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, rhel

When I do a yum update I need to reboot the instance. When I reboot AWS terminates the instance. I am using a rhel7 ami image. Anyone know how to fix this? I tried putting the instance in standby in auto-scaling with no effect.

```
sudo yum update -y
```

Comment: Was the Auto Scaling group already running at the `minimum` number of instances, such that putting this instance into standby caused the number of instances to drop below the minimum? When you called `enter_standby()`, what value did you provide for `ShouldDecrementDesiredCapacity`?

Comment: We did put the node in standby and detached it. We can do a reboot, but after a yum update it gets terminated even after we put it in standby and detach it.

Comment: You might want to check CloudTrail to see what terminated the instance. Auto Scaling would definitely not terminate an instance that is not part of an Auto Scaling group.